# WebRTC: peer connections limit?

Tags: html, webrtc

How many peer connections can I create on a single client? Is there any limit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you've arrived at 256 experimentally since there is currently no documentation/specs to suggest it. I don't know exactly how things have changed since 2013, but currently, my own experiments cap out at 500 simultaneous connections per page. As far as I can tell, Firefox has no such limit.

**The real limit, according to Chromium source code is 500** ([source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/modules/peerconnection/rtc_peer_connection.cc#144)). As far as I can tell, there was no limit before this was implemented ([source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/5a7f431061f415177cf391511d1331c5bd9b7773%5E%21/WebKit/Source/modules/peerconnection/RTCPeerConnection.cpp)) even going as far back as the WebKit days.

I think one reason that it can be tricky to keep track of is that Chrome (and FF for that matter) have always been bad at the garbage collection of dead connections. If you check `chrome://webrtc-internals` (FF equivalent: `about:webrtc`), there will often be a build-up of zombie connections that count towards the 500 limit. These persist until you manually destroy them, or close/refresh the page. One way to work around this is through your own heartbeat implementation or using the signalling server to notify of peers disconnecting such that other peers can destroy their connection (although this requires a persistent connection to a signalling server).

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Maximum peer connections limit is 256 (on chrome).**

Not sure about other major browsers, depending on your bandwidth they are limited to give certain stability.

Comment: Do you have the source?

Comment: Konga, I know about this limit, since it's documentated, I'm beginning a project and I'm curious if the limit is for Peer to Peer only?  Like, lets say you want to have your beautiful face on the homepage of your website, talking to your visitors, would that mean that only 256 visitors would be able to see it?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't find any evidence for this number anywhere on the internet. Would you mind clarifying how you arrived at it?

Comment: @tbh__ If you want to do live streaming from one-to-many at web scale, you should be using technology such as HLS or DASH. That will deliver your video to millions of users over HTTPS behind a CDN. Your source video would get chunked up and saved to cloud storage for mass consumption. The only problem is the technicalities of building a slicing media server with something like FFMPEG.

Comment: After real experiments, I can confirm that the practical P2P limit in a mesh network is **4-5 users** generally. After that the connections are unstable. Due to number of encoded upload streams being too high. Also note that, upload speeds are usually less than 1/5th of the download speeds. Here is my recent SO post on this topic: [Does WebRTC based audio/video conference have so many peer to peer OR all the upload are mixed somewhere and sent back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63930869/514235)

Comment: @iammilind You're certainly correct when we're talking about P2P mesh video conferencing, but OP wasn't asking about that, and I'm not sure why everyone assumed that. WebRTC with SFUs can certainly go far beyond that, as the bottleneck becomes video decoding, not bandwidth. Then there are many non-video, non-audio use cases for WebRTC (Datachannel networks), where it's totally possible to go into hundreds of connections.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is any hard limit(other than runtime memory), but there is certainly soft one.

If you are considering fully mesh topology(app in which every client is connected to every other client), then you have to consider main deficiency of this topology. For large number of participants in video conference session bandwidth which is required to sustain the overall session grows for each new participant.

Therefore, users with low bandwidth will not be able to handle video conference session with big number of participants.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting topic.. I was just watching this youtube video about Multi  Peer in WebRTC. The presenters said it just depend on the number of peers, but the highest he did was on less than 6 peers. Also this depends on your bandwidth size. The best thing you can do is to develop an WebRTC and try connecting with your friends and judge as this also depends on the country you are in. Like I live in Botswana and the network is not fast so i wont expect to be having 6 peers while I am still suffering to get a clear communication with only one person this side.

Comment: OP never said anything about P2P mesh, and also didn't say anything about video. In a typical conferencing setting, where everyone has video+audio on, with typical domestic internet connections, on typical devices, you can't guarantee acceptable user experience even beyond 4 participants. And like you said, those factors vary a lot, e.g. across countries. But WebRTC isn't just for P2P mesh networks, and isn't just for video, so you can certainly go far above that for other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](https://webrtc.ventures/2017/11/a-guide-to-webrtc-media-servers-open-source-options/):

> In practice, even under optimal network conditions, a mesh video call doesn’t work well beyond five participants.

Comment: OP never said anything about either mesh, or video.

Comment: And yet most people would care about such things.

Comment: This is a worthwhile fact but belongs as a comment not answer