# Does WebRTC based audio/video conference have so many peer to peer OR all the upload are mixed somewhere and sent back?

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc, html5-video, p2p

Suppose we establish a WebRTC conference among A, B & C. Then will there be A <--> B, A <--> C, B <--> C individual calls?

**Qn-1**: **If yes, then isn't that inefficient?** Because each peer uploads the same data twice.

Now, Google has a different strategy for conferences. In their official document, it reads:

> ### [Does classic Hangouts use peer-to-peer calling for a Hangout with more than two participants?](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6334301?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20improve%20audio%20and%20video,through%20one%20of%20Google%27s%20servers.)
>
> Peer-to-peer connections are used only for calls with two participants. If any additional participants join, classic Hangouts will immediately go back to sending and receiving data using the connection to the Google server.

**Qn-2**: Now suppose if we go with p2p approach nevertheless. Now somehow we route all the traffic to one single port. Then is there any WebRTC limitation on how many connections can it make at a same time to a same IP and same port?

The reason for above question is that, if we do that with some hacks then after 4 outgoing connections, the 5th connection will always be unstable and mostly fail.

Comment: Peer-to-peer conference is unsustainable.

Comment: @AlexCohn, can you plz elaborate more on this why is not sustainable. Is it not possible for more than 4-5 users?

Comment: Yes WebRTC connections are always peer-to-peer, there is no client-server option. I don't see the advantage of routing traffic from multiple peers to a single local socket. It won't change the bandwidth, CPU or memory required.

Comment: @sipwiz, why most of the solutions route their traffic for conference via central server? Is it because too many peers will create too much of upload data of repeating nature?

Comment: For larger numbers of streams (the consensus seems to be > 5) a central server, which for WebRTC typically operates as an SFU or MCU, has some big advantages. It will also have some big costs. Lots of information available about this trade-off.

Comment: @sipwiz, can you share those information or links. Also, does that mean that for more than 5 users, peer-to-peer is not a good choice or impractical.

Comment: @sipwiz, also any comment on this post which says that p2p limit is 256-500!? [WebRTC: peer connections limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015304/webrtc-peer-connections-limit)

Comment: There's a difference between a `WebRTC connection` and a `WebRTC connection with an audio/video stream`. My comments above refer to the latter and the bandwidth/CPU needed for something like a 1080p video stream.

Comment: @sipsorcery WebRTC isn't exclusively Peer to Peer. While the spec may say "Peer to Peer" all over it there's nothing within it that prevents a client server relationship. Many services use WebRTC for other than Peer to Peer. including services from Google and Apple who both played a major part in creating the spec...

Comment: Cool example is livestreaming on youtube. This is a hybrid model but obviously not peer to peer.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's happening at the app layer, the WebRTC transport protocol is P2P. The machine you are calling "server" is just another peer as far as WebRTC is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

There is enough material to suggest that the **P2P based "Mesh" network is suitable for up to 4 user stable conference**.

- [This video](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) states that "Mesh" network is the most naive way to implement a conference
  [image]
- [This link](https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/scalability-in-video-conferencing-part-1-276f52b4acac) suggests that the bandwidth is overwhelmed and the quality reduces as the participants increase in P2P:
  [image]
- In [this link](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-multiparty-video-alternatives/), it states that "Mesh" network starts failing as the number of participants increase.
  [image]